# Solving the laplacian over a square

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, solution-verification, harmonic-functions

I am preparing for an upcoming exam, and I was solving the following boundary value problem

$$\Delta u(x,y)=0,\ (x,y)\in [0,\pi]^2$$ $$u_y(x,0)=0,\ u_y(x,\pi)=0$$ $$u(0,y)=0$$ $$u(\pi,y)=\cos^2y$$

I tried separation of variables, asusming $u(x,y)=X(x)Y(y)$ and solved it, putting in the boundary conditions and got (assuming the solutions are not trivially zero)

$$X(x)=A(e^{nx}-e^{-nx})$$ $$Y(y)=D\cos(ny)$$ for some constants $A,D$. I then put them together and wrote $$u(x,y)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty A_n(e^{nx}-e^{-nx})\cos(ny)$$ where the $A_n$ are constants to be determined. Am I correct in writing this?

Assuming it is correct, I put in the last boundary condition and using the orthogonality of the fourier basis, I get

$$A_n=\frac{2/\pi}{e^{n\pi}-e^{-n\pi}}\int_0^\pi \cos^2y\cos(ny)\ \mathrm dy$$

which only survives when $n=2$ (for the rest, it is $0$). For $n=2$, it gives $$A_2=\frac{1}{2(e^{2\pi}-e^{-2\pi})}$$

Then plugging in this in the solution, I have

$$u(x,y)=\frac1{2(e^{2\pi}-e^{-2\pi})}(e^{2x}-e^{-2x})\cos(2y)$$

---

But here is the problem. The final solution doesn't seem to be satisfying the last boundary condition. It gives

$$u(\pi,y)=\frac12\cos(2y)=\cos^2y-\frac12$$ where there is an extra factor of $1/2$. I have been looking at it for hours but I can't find where the error creeps in. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: @Gonçalo Ah, maybe that's the problem! But somehow n=0 doesn't give me anything after I have solved the separated equations. Do I need to assume that the constant of separation is 0 and solve separately? Sorry if it is a very naive question.

Comment: @HackR: It's not clear exactly where in your solution that you think it doesn't give you anything. But $u(x,y) = A_0 x + \frac12 \frac{\sinh(2x)}{\sinh(2\pi)} \cos(2y)$ works if you choose the suitable value of $A_0$, right?

Comment: @HansLundmark Hi, yes that works. But I am not really seeing how the $A_0x$ term appears. It can't arise in the the formula for $A_n$ as the denominator vanishes, and it can't appear in the relation for $X(x)$ because then $X(x)$ vanishes identically.

Comment: Yes, that answers my question. Thank you. I can see how to get that term now. If you write it as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Correct solution is $$u(x,y)=\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{(e^{2 x}-e^{-2 x}) \cos (2 y)}{e^{2 \pi}-e^{-2 \pi}}+\frac{x}{\pi }\right)$$